# Scripture against obscenity

Tags: cursing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Bible say about "bad" words?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/774/what-does-the-bible-say-about-bad-words)

I know that swearing and using obscenity is wrong, but I'm curious what exactly are the Scriptures that support this.  Is there any Scripture that clearly states that using obscenity is wrong? or is swearing/blaspheming/obscenity wrong because it violates key values and doctrines of Christianity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bible prevents obscenity in many cases. Keep in mind that speech is a gift from God, so we must ask ourselves how he use this gift. Also, using obscenity usually shows what is in heart. Here are some verses that support this:

**Ephesians 5:3,4**

> But among you there must not be even a hint of sexual immorality, or
>   of any kind of impurity, or of greed, because these are improper for
>   God’s holy people. 4 Nor should there be obscenity, foolish talk or
>   coarse joking, which are out of place, but rather thanksgiving.

**Ephesians 4:31**

> Get rid of all bitterness, rage and anger, brawling and **slander**, along
>   with every form of malice.

**Psalms 19:14**

> May these words of my mouth and this meditation of my heart    be
>   pleasing in your sight,    LORD, my Rock and my Redeemer.

**Luke 6:45**

> A good man brings good things out of the good stored up in his heart,
>   and an evil man brings evil things out of the evil stored up in his
>   heart. **For the mouth speaks what the heart is full of**.